# Priority queue javascript

Tags: javascript, data-structures

In the below priority queue when enqueueing element with same priority they  are added adjacent to each other but i cant see any particular condition regarding that.

```
    function PriorityQueue() {
    var collection = [];
    this.printCollection = function() {
      (console.log(collection));
    };
    this.enqueue = function(element){
        if (this.isEmpty()){ 
            collection.push(element);
        } else {
            var added = false;
            for (var i=0; i<collection.length; i++){
                 if (element[1] < collection[i][1]){ //checking priorities
                    collection.splice(i,0,element);
                    added = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (!added){
                collection.push(element);
            }
        }
    };
    this.dequeue = function() {
        var value = collection.shift();
        return value[0];
       };
    this.front = function() {
        return collection[0];
    };
    this.size = function() {
        return collection.length; 
    };
    this.isEmpty = function() {
        return (collection.length === 0); 
    };
}

var pq = new PriorityQueue(); 
pq.enqueue(['Beau Carnes', 2]); 
pq.enqueue(['Quincy Larson', 3]);
pq.enqueue(['Ewa Mitulska-Wójcik', 1])
pq.enqueue(['Briana Swift', 2])
pq.printCollection();
pq.dequeue();
console.log(pq.front());
pq.printCollection();
```

Element with higher priority get added to the end but element with same priority is added adjacent to each other...

Comment: `collection.splice(i,0,element);`

Comment: In that if block it says if priority of element is less than the elements in collection then replace the respected element what if element priority is same

Comment: Please see how splice works: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice

Comment: collection.splice(i,**0**,element); here the `0` indicates no element to be deleted

Comment: if i try to do so pq.enqueue(['Something', 2]) why it is adding adjacent to Briana Swift it has to fail in the if condition right .Plz try to explain the Enqueue if condition.

Comment: I've tried to explain below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The condition is in the splice call

`collection.splice(i,0,element);`

explaining the enqueue function

```
 this.enqueue = function(element){
        //check if collection is empty push the element
        if (this.isEmpty()){ 
            collection.push(element);
        } else {
            //Set a flag to check if element added 
            //(this is to determine is the for loop found a match)
            var added = false;
            for (var i=0; i<collection.length; i++){
                 //if the element at the index 'i' in the collection has
                 //higher priority you need the splice the array at that 
                 //index and insert the element there
                 if (element[1] < collection[i][1]){ //checking priorities
                    //splice the array at that index and insert the element
                    collection.splice(i,0,element);
                    //satisfy the added condition
                    added = true;
                    //break the for loop
                    break;
                }
            }
            //if not added in the loop
            if (!added){
                //push to the end on the collection
                collection.push(element);
            }
        }
    };
```

Answer (score -1):

you can use the below mentioned library. just do npm install collectiondatalib.

FEATURES:https://www.npmjs.com/package/collectiondatalib

EASY TO USE and all collections and searching sorting methods are available.

you can find the source code also on that page.